# python logging to multiple files

Tags: python, django, logging, python-logging

Does someone has an example of logging in python to 2 or more different logfiles.

I want to log for example to '/tmp/foo.log' and '/tmp/bar.log'.

Answer (score 19):

Here's an example:

```
import logging
logger1 = logging.getLogger('1')
logger1.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('/tmp/logger1'))
logger2 = logging.getLogger('2')
logger2.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('/tmp/logger2'))

logger1.error('1')
logger2.error('2')
```

Then,

```
 $ cat /tmp/logger1
 1
 $ cat /tmp/logger2
 2
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a complete working example based on the example in logging.html. The main 'gotcha' to note is that you have to be sure to set the log level for the root logger to interact correctly with the files.

```
import logging

logging.getLogger('').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
def create_log_file(filename, level=logging.INFO):
    handler = logging.FileHandler(filename)
    handler.setLevel(level)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logging.getLogger('').addHandler(handler)

create_log_file('/temp/log1.log', logging.DEBUG)
create_log_file('/temp/log2.log', logging.INFO)

# Now, we can log to the root logger, or any other logger. First the root...
logging.info('Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz.')

# Now, define a couple of other loggers which might represent areas in your
# application:

logger1 = logging.getLogger('myapp.area1')
logger2 = logging.getLogger('myapp.area2')

logger1.debug('Quick zephyrs blow, vexing daft Jim.')
logger1.info('How quickly daft jumping zebras vex.')
logger2.warning('Jail zesty vixen who grabbed pay from quack.')
logger2.error('The five boxing wizards jump quickly.')
```

Comment: but in this example all root messages will apear in log1.log and log2.log aswell?

Comment: that's because it is just an example. If you want you can attach the handlers to a different logger.

Comment: Why you attack this post, i just asked for an example and the post of Duncan helped me much better than the documentation. So thank you Duncan for your help. But 1 more question, is it possible to put on each logger a rotation ?

Comment: @Hein: try the Python 3.2 version of the docs, they may make more sense than the 2.7 version: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/logging.html. And yes, `logging` provides a `RotatingFileHandler` that lets you rotate log files easily.